# How to convert a list to a jagged array in c#?

Tags: c#

I am calling a third party API that expect a jagged array as input but I need to build this list dynamically.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var slots = new DateTime[][]
                {
                    new DateTime[] {new DateTime(2020, 2, 14), new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)},
                    new DateTime[] {new DateTime(2020, 2, 15), new DateTime(2020, 2, 23)},
                    new DateTime[] {new DateTime(2020, 2, 16), new DateTime(2020, 2, 24)}
                };

                DateTime[][] slots2;
                List<DateTime> appointments=new List<DateTime>();
                appointments.Add(new DateTime(2020, 2, 14));
                appointments.Add(new DateTime(2020, 2, 20));
                slots2 = appointments.ToArray();
            }
        }

}
```

in the above code when I try to initialize the jagged array slots  with datetime objects it works fine but when I try to use appointments list I get an error with slots2. How to initialize slot2 with a list of date time to populate slots2?

Comment: Did you mean `List<DateTime[]> appointments=new List<DateTime[]>();` or `DateTime[] slots2;`? Currently `slots2` is a type of `DateTime[][]` but `appointments` is equivalent to `DateTime[]`.

Comment: I want to initialize slot2 with a dynamic list of datetime

Comment: slot2 has to be a jagged array and I want to initialize it with a dynamic list. That is my problem

Comment: By that logic you should change your `List<DateTime> appointments` to a `List<DateTime[]>`. What you have currently is the equivalent of a single dimensional array of `DateTime` objects, which cannot be a jagged array as jagged arrays are multidimensional.

Comment: Currently it's not entirely clear what the expected value of `slots2` _should_ be. Could you please provide an example of what you expect the value of `slots2` to look like in your question? Or is `slots` at the top an example of an expected value for `slots2`?

Comment: slots2 expect a value similar to slots but I want to build it from a dynamic list

Comment: @RobertSmith That doesn't answer AlphaDelta's question. Please [edit] the question, provide an example of `appointments` (preferably with more than two items), **AND** _also_ provide the expected values that `slots2` should hold. Don't just describe them. Show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise it first.

```
// create 1 element in the first dimension
var slots2 = new DateTime[1][];

var appointments = new List<DateTime>
                              {
                                 new DateTime(2020, 2, 14),
                                 new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)
                              };

// add the second dimension to the first element you created
slots2[0] = appointments.ToArray();
```

or

```
var slots2 = new[]
            {
               new[]
               {
                  new DateTime(2020, 2, 14),
                  new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)
               }
            };
```

**Edit**

Why not just use `List<List<DateTime>>` and *project* them into arrays

```
var appointments = new List<List<DateTime>>
                   {
                      new List<DateTime>
                      {
                         new DateTime(2020, 2, 14),
                         new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)
                      }
                   };
```

Then you can add more

```
 appointments.Add(new List<DateTime>
    {
       new DateTime(2020, 2, 14),
       new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)
    });

var slots2 = appointments.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: that is close to what I want but not exactly because the appointments are based on user input and may vary in length that is why I do not now at run time how many items I will have in first dimension (i.e [1] in the above code)